# Flutter: Unable to go to login view from a persistent bottom nav bar based view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I have a persistent bottom nav bar based on [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar).

The plugin allows building a page with few footer buttons and navigation etc. But, Once such a page has a logout button that must send the user back to Login view (outside of navbar) and I am stuck here. I've permuted with all the navigator operations available and am stuck here, unable to show a page without the bottom navbar appearing.

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: share your code

Comment: Hi @JahidulIslam the problem and example is almost similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560425/flutter-bottom-navigation-bar-with-nested-navigation-and-restoring-the-root-pag?noredirect=1#comment122198935_67560425).  :)